# Can't find file I created

Tags: java, io

I am new to java and I have a problem with finding a file I created that is usually visible within Eclipse.After running and refreshing multiple times I still don't see it.Here is my code, any help would be welcome.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner x= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("You got a high score!");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Please enter your score: ");

    int score = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");

    String name = x.nextLine();

    input.close();

    File file = new File("highscore.txt");

    try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))){

        bw.write(score);
        bw.write(name);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File is not found");;
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be in your project, relative to the package

Comment: 1) You only need one Scanner object. 2) Your `name` variable is empty. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Comment: I tried with one scanner, but then I couldn't input name when I was asked, so I added the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the absolute path.

```
File file = new File("highscore.txt");
System.out.println("file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help guys. It was some kind of weird bug and I solved it by restarting my PC. I have one other question though. My text file didn't store int correctly so I needed to change my score value to String. Why is that and what kind of file can I use that accepts both Strings and Integers?

Answer (score -1):

The file will be created where your class file is created.
Ex - Say your file name path is "c:\dinesh\com\dinesh\MyFirstProgram.java". When you compile your file, you will have class file will be in "c:\dinesh\com\dinesh\MyFirstProgram.**class**". After the program runs, you will find the file in "c:\dinesh\com\dinesh\highscore.txt"

Comment: OP specifically mentions being new to Java and using Eclipse. Eclipse will store class files in the {workspace}/{project}/bin/{package} folder assuming a standard Java Project setup. The working directory by default is the project folder not the folder in which the class file is stored.